# Guidance needed: Error in Downloading Python for Eclipse Juno

Tags: python, eclipse

I tried to download Python for Eclipse Juno via http://pydev.org/updates

I keep getting the error:

```
    An error occurred while installing the items
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, 
    operand=null --> [R]org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.jar 1.8.3, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallFeatureAction).
    The artifact file for org.eclipse.update.feature,org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature,1.8.3 was not found.
```

I cannot find a solution. Could someone guide me a little.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" ? (in the available software page)

You can try to manually install it :

- download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/
- Extract the contents of the zip file in the `eclipse/dropins` folder and restart Eclipse.

If it's still not working, you can try removing/adding back the Eclipse Project Update site (to have the metadata recalculated)

And try unchecking the above option

Comment: Yes I checked that box